Mocking pytest test with @patch unittest.mock decorator
Issue with Mocking send_request() in Unit Tests
I'm having trouble with mocking the send_request() function in my tests. Despite using patch, the original send_request() function is being called, and the mock isn't applied. Here's the relevant output and code:
Output:
Send_click
send_request mock: <function send_request at 0x7f9c2146de40>
send request

Code:
logic.py
def send_request(manager, action_method, url, data=None, params=None, headers=None):
    print("send request")

test_ui.py
from ..ui import UserInterface
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

@patch("ui.send_request")
def test_send_request(mock_send_request, qtbot):
    ui = UserInterface()
    ui.get_request_data = Mock()
    data = QByteArray(data_str_create.encode("utf-8"))
    action_method, url, data = ACTIONS_METHODS.POST, QUrl("http://example.com/api"), data
    ui.get_request_data.return_value = action_method, url, data
    ui.send_click()
    mock_send_request.assert_called_once()

Issue:

send_request() is not mocked; the original function is being executed. Proven by send request in the output and function type in the output.
The AssertionError in the last line of the test indicates that the mock was not applied.

How send_request() is used:
ui.py
from logic import handle_response, send_request

class UserInterface(QWidget):
    # other methods

    def get_request_data(self):
        action_method = self.combo_box.currentText()
        json_dict = json.loads(
            self.body.toPlainText().encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
        )
        json_data = json.dumps(json_dict).encode("utf-8")
        data = QByteArray(json_data)
        url = QUrl(self.url.text())
        return action_method, url, data

    def send_click(self):
        print("Send_click")
        print(f"send_request mock: {send_request}")
        send_request(self.rest_manager, *self.get_request_data())

Can someone help figure out why the send_request() function is not being mocked as expected?

I have sys.path.append("/home/projectpath")  in conftest.py. Does it matter?

The structure of your project in my system
I have created in my system the following structure of your project:
project
  |- ui.py
  |- logic.py
  |- test
       |- test_ui.py

The code of the file test_ui.py
I have modified your test_ui.py file as following:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/project")
from ui import UserInterface


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("ui.send_request")
    def test_send_request(self, qtbot):
        ui = UserInterface()
        ui.get_request_data = Mock()
        #data = QByteArray(data_str_create.encode("utf-8"))
        #action_method, url, data = ACTIONS_METHODS.POST, QUrl("http://example.com/api"), data
        #ui.get_request_data.return_value = action_method, url, data
        ui.get_request_data.return_value = "action_method", "url", "data"
        ui.send_click()
        qtbot.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

The changes to your test file
I have defined test_send_request() as a method of MyTestCase class that is a subclass of MyTestCase.
The most important changes to your test_send_request() method are:

set ui.get_request_data.return_value to "action_method", "url", "data" to simplify the execution (I don't have the code of QWidget, ACTIONS_METHODS and so on)
change the instruction mock_send_request.assert_called_once() to qtbot.assert_called_once()
I have modified your import as following:

sys.path.append("/path/to/project")
from ui import UserInterface

The output of the test execution
In this way the output of the execution is:
Send_click
send_request mock: <MagicMock name='send_request' id='140010776190368'>

In the output misses the string:
send request

as you wish and the test is successfully pass.
